# IntelliJ Idea Error: Abnormal build process termination - failed to create a child event loop

Tags: java, windows, intellij-idea

I am a new IntelliJ Idea user. After installing the IntelliJ Idea, I can not run my code, the build process getting terminated! I tried to upgrade my JDK version, uninstall Nvidia software, uninstall and install several times both the IDE and JDK, correcting my environment variables but still, I got the same problem! How can I solve this issue? I tried to almost all solutions provided by StackOverflow before, but nothing works! What should I do?

[This is the screenshot of my code with error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6kgyz.png)

**Error: Abnormal build process termination:**

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_241\bin\java.exe" -Xmx700m
-Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.endorsed.dirs=\"\" -Djdt.compiler.useSingleThread=true -Dpreload.project.path=C:/Users/RYANS/IdeaProjects/HelloJava -Dpreload.config.path=C:/Users/RYANS/.IdeaIE2019.3/config/options -Dcompile.parallel=false -Drebuild.on.dependency.change=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dio.netty.initialSeedUniquifier=7347025144299434831 -Dfile.encoding=windows-1252 -Duser.language=en -Duser.country=US -Didea.paths.selector=IdeaIE2019.3 "-Didea.home.path=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Educational Edition 2019.3.3"
-Didea.config.path=C:\Users\RYANS/.IdeaIE2019.3/config -Didea.plugins.path=C:\Users\RYANS/.IdeaIE2019.3/config/plugins -Djps.log.dir=C:/Users/RYANS/.IdeaIE2019.3/system/log/build-log "-Djps.fallback.jdk.home=C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Educational Edition 2019.3.3/jbr" -Djps.fallback.jdk.version=11.0.5
-Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:/Users/RYANS/.IdeaIE2019.3/system/compile-server/hellojava_c3eff408/_temp_
-Djps.backward.ref.index.builder=true -Dkotlin.incremental.compilation=true -Dkotlin.incremental.compilation.js=true -Dkotlin.daemon.enabled -Dkotlin.daemon.client.alive.path=\"C:\Users\RYANS\AppData\Local\Temp\kotlin-idea-8416770196096947258-is-running\"
-Dscala.compiler.indices.rebuild=true -classpath "C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Educational Edition
2019.3.3/plugins/java/lib/jps-launcher.jar;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_241/lib/tools.jar" org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.Launcher "C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Educational Edition
2019.3.3/plugins/java/lib/aether-connector-basic-1.1.0.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Educational Edition
2019.3.3/plugins/java/lib/jps-builders-6.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Educational Edition
2019.3.3/lib/netty-common-4.1.41.Final.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Educational Edition
2019.3.3/plugins/java/lib/aether-dependency-resolver.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Educational Edition
2019.3.3/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Educational Edition 2019.3.3/lib/jps-model.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Educational Edition
2019.3.3/lib/idea_rt.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Educational Edition
2019.3.3/plugins/java/lib/maven-builder-support-3.3.9.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Educational Edition
2019.3.3/plugins/java/lib/maven-model-builder-3.3.9.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Educational Edition
2019.3.3/plugins/java/lib/maven-aether-provider-3.3.9.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Educational Edition
2019.3.3/lib/commons-logging-1.2.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Educational Edition
2019.3.3/lib/jna-platform.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Educational Edition 2019.3.3/lib/oro-2.0.8.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Educational Edition
2019.3.3/lib/asm-all-7.0.1.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Educational Edition 2019.3.3/lib/nanoxml-2.2.3.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Educational Edition
2019.3.3/plugins/java/lib/maven-repository-metadata-3.3.9.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Educational Edition
2019.3.3/plugins/java/lib/aether-util-1.1.0.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Educational Edition
2019.3.3/lib/httpclient-4.5.10.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Educational Edition
2019.3.3/plugins/java/lib/aether-spi-1.1.0.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Educational Edition
2019.3.3/lib/guava-27.1-jre.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Educational Edition 2019.3.3/lib/jna.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Educational Edition
2019.3.3/lib/gson-2.8.5.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Educational Edition
2019.3.3/plugins/java/lib/maven-model-3.3.9.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Educational Edition
2019.3.3/lib/netty-codec-4.1.41.Final.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Educational Edition
2019.3.3/lib/protobuf-java-3.5.1.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Educational Edition
2019.3.3/lib/log4j.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Educational Edition 2019.3.3/lib/platform-api.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Educational Edition
2019.3.3/lib/jdom.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Educational Edition
2019.3.3/plugins/java/lib/plexus-utils-3.0.22.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Educational Edition
2019.3.3/lib/forms-1.1-preview.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Educational Edition
2019.3.3/plugins/java/lib/plexus-interpolation-1.21.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Educational Edition
2019.3.3/lib/trove4j.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Educational Edition
2019.3.3/plugins/java/lib/commons-lang3-3.4.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Educational Edition
2019.3.3/plugins/java/lib/javac2.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Educational Edition
2019.3.3/plugins/java/lib/maven-artifact-3.3.9.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Educational Edition
2019.3.3/lib/httpcore-4.4.12.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Educational Edition
2019.3.3/plugins/java/lib/aether-impl-1.1.0.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Educational Edition
2019.3.3/plugins/java/lib/aether-transport-http-1.1.0.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Educational Edition
2019.3.3/lib/annotations.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Educational Edition
2019.3.3/plugins/java/lib/plexus-component-annotations-1.6.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Educational Edition
2019.3.3/plugins/java/lib/jps-builders.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Educational Edition
2019.3.3/plugins/java/lib/aether-transport-file-1.1.0.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Educational Edition
2019.3.3/lib/qdox-2.0-M10.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Educational Edition 2019.3.3/lib/resources_en.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Educational Edition
2019.3.3/lib/netty-transport-4.1.41.Final.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Educational Edition
2019.3.3/lib/lz4-java-1.6.0.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Educational Edition
2019.3.3/lib/netty-buffer-4.1.41.Final.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Educational Edition
2019.3.3/plugins/java/lib/aether-api-1.1.0.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Educational Edition
2019.3.3/lib/netty-resolver-4.1.41.Final.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Educational Edition
2019.3.3/lib/util.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Educational Edition 2019.3.3/lib/gson-2.8.5.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Educational Edition
2019.3.3/plugins/android/lib/jarutils.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Educational Edition
2019.3.3/lib/guava-27.1-jre.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Educational Edition
2019.3.3/plugins/android/lib/common-26.5.0.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Educational Edition
2019.3.3/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-api-5.2.1-sp1.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Educational Edition
2019.3.3/lib/gson-2.8.5.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Educational Edition
2019.3.3/plugins/android/lib/jarutils.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Educational Edition
2019.3.3/lib/guava-27.1-jre.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Educational Edition
2019.3.3/plugins/android/lib/common-26.5.0.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Educational Edition
2019.3.3/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-api-5.2.1-sp1.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Educational Edition
2019.3.3/plugins/ant/lib/ant-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Educational Edition
2019.3.3/plugins/IntelliLang/lib/intellilang-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Educational Edition
2019.3.3/plugins/Groovy/lib/groovy-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Educational Edition
2019.3.3/plugins/Groovy/lib/groovy-rt-constants.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Educational Edition
2019.3.3/plugins/maven/lib/maven-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Educational Edition
2019.3.3/plugins/gradle-java/lib/gradle-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Educational Edition
2019.3.3/plugins/uiDesigner/lib/jps/ui-designer-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Educational Edition
2019.3.3/plugins/devkit/lib/devkit-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Educational Edition
2019.3.3/plugins/Kotlin/lib/jps/kotlin-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Educational Edition
2019.3.3/plugins/Kotlin/lib/kotlin-stdlib.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Educational Edition
2019.3.3/plugins/Kotlin/lib/kotlin-reflect.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Educational Edition
2019.3.3/plugins/Kotlin/lib/kotlin-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Educational Edition
2019.3.3/plugins/eclipse/lib/eclipse-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Educational Edition
2019.3.3/plugins/eclipse/lib/common-eclipse-util.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Educational Edition
2019.3.3/plugins/android/lib/jps/android-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Educational Edition
2019.3.3/plugins/android/lib/android-common.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Educational Edition
2019.3.3/plugins/android/lib/build-common.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Educational Edition
2019.3.3/plugins/android/lib/android-rt.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Educational Edition
2019.3.3/plugins/android/lib/intellij.android.kotlin.extensions.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Educational Edition
2019.3.3/plugins/android/lib/sdk-common-26.5.0.2.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Educational Edition
2019.3.3/plugins/android/lib/common-26.5.0.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Educational Edition
2019.3.3/plugins/android/lib/repository-26.5.0.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Educational Edition
2019.3.3/plugins/android/lib/sdklib-26.5.0.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Educational Edition
2019.3.3/plugins/android/lib/jarutils.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Educational Edition
2019.3.3/plugins/android/lib/layoutlib-api-26.5.0.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Educational Edition
2019.3.3/plugins/android/lib/manifest-merger-26.5.0.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Educational Edition
2019.3.3/plugins/Scala/lib/scala-library.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Educational Edition
2019.3.3/plugins/Scala/lib/compiler-shared.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Educational Edition
2019.3.3/plugins/Scala/lib/jps/nailgun.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Educational Edition
2019.3.3/plugins/Scala/lib/jps/compiler-jps.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Educational Edition
2019.3.3/plugins/Scala/lib/jps/sbt-interface.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Educational Edition
2019.3.3/plugins/Scala/lib/jps/incremental-compiler.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Educational Edition
2019.3.3/plugins/Scala/lib/spray-json_2.12-1.3.4.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Educational Edition
2019.3.3/plugins/Scala/lib/scala-compiler-indices-protocol_2.12-0.1.1.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Educational Edition
2019.3.3/plugins/javaFX/lib/javaFX-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Educational Edition
2019.3.3/plugins/javaFX/lib/common-javaFX-plugin.jar" org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain 127.0.0.1 2999 8adac4bc-408b-4960-b1eb-48ba2c90a482 C:/Users/RYANS/.IdeaIE2019.3/system/compile-server Build process started. Classpath: C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Educational Edition
2019.3.3/plugins/java/lib/jps-launcher.jar;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_241/lib/tools.jar SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder". SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details. Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:2999; reason: failed to create a child event loop java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to create a child event loop  at io.netty.util.concurrent.MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.java:88)     at io.netty.util.concurrent.MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.java:58)     at io.netty.util.concurrent.MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.java:47)     at io.netty.channel.MultithreadEventLoopGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventLoopGroup.java:59)     at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.<init>(NioEventLoopGroup.java:78)     at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.<init>(NioEventLoopGroup.java:73)     at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.<init>(NioEventLoopGroup.java:60)     at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain.main(BuildMain.java:92)  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:58) Caused by: io.netty.channel.ChannelException: failed to open a new selector    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.openSelector(NioEventLoop.java:181)    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.<init>(NioEventLoop.java:147)  at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.newChild(NioEventLoopGroup.java:138)  at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.newChild(NioEventLoopGroup.java:37)   at io.netty.util.concurrent.MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.java:84)     ... 12 more Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to establish loopback connection     at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer.run(PipeImpl.java:94)    at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer.run(PipeImpl.java:61)    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl.<init>(PipeImpl.java:171)    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorProviderImpl.openPipe(SelectorProviderImpl.java:50)   at java.nio.channels.Pipe.open(Pipe.java:155)   at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl.<init>(WindowsSelectorImpl.java:127)  at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorProvider.openSelector(WindowsSelectorProvider.java:44)     at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.openSelector(NioEventLoop.java:179)    ... 16 more Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect     at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)   at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:454)     at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:446)     at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(SocketChannelImpl.java:648)     at java.nio.channels.SocketChannel.open(SocketChannel.java:189)     at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer$LoopbackConnector.run(PipeImpl.java:127)     at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer.run(PipeImpl.java:76)    ... 24 more
Exiting.
```

Comment: Does `netsh winsock reset` followed by the reboot help?

Comment: Try adding `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true` and see if it helps.

Comment: @CrazyCoder yes I did and restart my computer also. but it's still there!

Comment: Any blocked ports in `netsh interface ipv4 show excludedportrange protocol=tcp` list? Does disabling antivirus/firewall help? Do you have loopback interface working?

Comment: @KarolDowbecki where to add this?

Comment: @CrazyCoder I don't have any antivirus.

Comment: @IftekharulIslam you have Windows Defender enabled by default. Disabling the firewall is known to help with similar issues, see [this comment](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-156124?focusedCommentId=563758&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-563758).

Comment: @CrazyCoder Thank you mate. Thanks a lot, I just didn't know my Windows Defender still firewalled my PC. After disabling it now it works fine.

Comment: @CrazyCoder I did it already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have Windows Defender enabled by default. Disabling the firewall is known to help with similar issues, see [this comment](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-156124?focusedCommentId=563758&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-563758):

> - Go to Windows Defender settings
> - Then go to firewall & network protection
> - Disable private network (active)

Your firewall is probably configured incorrectly as it should not block loopback interface (localhost) connections by default.

The stacktrace indicates that the issue is networking related:

```
Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:2999; reason: failed to create a child event loop
java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to create a child event loop
at io.netty.util.concurrent.MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.(MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.java:88)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.(MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.java:58)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.(MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.java:47)
at io.netty.channel.MultithreadEventLoopGroup.(MultithreadEventLoopGroup.java:59)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.(NioEventLoopGroup.java:78)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.(NioEventLoopGroup.java:73)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.(NioEventLoopGroup.java:60)
at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain.main(BuildMain.java:92)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:58)
Caused by: io.netty.channel.ChannelException: failed to open a new selector
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.openSelector(NioEventLoop.java:181)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.(NioEventLoop.java:147)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.newChild(NioEventLoopGroup.java:138)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.newChild(NioEventLoopGroup.java:37)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.(MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.java:84)
... 12 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to establish loopback connection
at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer.run(PipeImpl.java:94)
at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer.run(PipeImpl.java:61)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl.(PipeImpl.java:171)
at sun.nio.ch.SelectorProviderImpl.openPipe(SelectorProviderImpl.java:50)
at java.nio.channels.Pipe.open(Pipe.java:155)
at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl.(WindowsSelectorImpl.java:127)
at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorProvider.openSelector(WindowsSelectorProvider.java:44)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.openSelector(NioEventLoop.java:179)
... 16 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:454)
at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:446)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(SocketChannelImpl.java:648)
at java.nio.channels.SocketChannel.open(SocketChannel.java:189)
at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer$LoopbackConnector.run(PipeImpl.java:127)
at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer.run(PipeImpl.java:76)
... 24 more
```