# Intellij maven build not working: Abnormal build process termination

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I spent all day long trying to resolve this but I would like to ask for assistance:

I'm getting this error when I try to build my maven project:

```
Abnormal build process termination: 
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.16\bin\java.exe" -Xmx700m -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dcompile.parallel=false -Drebuild.on.dependency.change=true -Didea.IntToIntBtree.page.size=32768 -Djdt.compiler.useSingleThread=true -Daether.connector.resumeDownloads=false -Dio.netty.initialSeedUniquifier=217246297037114181 -Dfile.encoding=windows-1252 -Duser.language=pt -Duser.country=BR -Didea.paths.selector=IntelliJIdea2022.2 "-Didea.home.path=C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2.3" -Didea.config.path=C:/Users/dmatte/AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2022.2 -Didea.plugins.path=C:/Users/dmatte/AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2022.2/plugins -Djps.log.dir=C:/Users/dmatte/AppData/Local/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2022.2/log/build-log "-Djps.fallback.jdk.home=C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2.3/jbr" -Djps.fallback.jdk.version=17.0.4.1 -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:/Users/dmatte/AppData/Local/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2022.2/compile-server/partner-accountant-connect_df39f5f1/_temp_ -Djps.backward.ref.index.builder=true -Dkotlin.incremental.compilation=true -Dkotlin.incremental.compilation.js=true -Dkotlin.daemon.enabled -Dkotlin.daemon.client.alive.path=\"C:\Users\dmatte\AppData\Local\Temp\kotlin-idea-15629753851594967133-is-running\" "-Djps.kotlin.home=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2.3\plugins\Kotlin\kotlinc" -Dtmh.instrument.annotations=true -Dtmh.generate.line.numbers=true -Dide.propagate.context=false -classpath "C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2.3/plugins/java/lib/jps-launcher.jar" org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.Launcher "C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2.3/plugins/java/lib/jps-builders.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2.3/plugins/java/lib/jps-builders-6.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2.3/plugins/java/lib/jps-javac-extension.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2.3/lib/util.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2.3/lib/util_rt.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2.3/lib/annotations.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2.3/lib/3rd-party-rt.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2.3/lib/jna.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2.3/lib/lz4-java.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2.3/lib/protobuf.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2.3/lib/jps-model.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2.3/plugins/java/lib/javac2.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2.3/lib/forms_rt.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2.3/plugins/java/lib/aether-dependency-resolver.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2.3/lib/idea_rt.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2.3/plugins/Kotlin/lib/jps/kotlin-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2.3/lib/util.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2.3/plugins/JavaEE/lib/jasper-v2-rt.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2.3/plugins/eclipse/lib/eclipse-jps.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2.3/plugins/eclipse/lib/eclipse-common.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2.3/plugins/space/lib/space-java-jps.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2.3/plugins/uiDesigner/lib/jps/java-guiForms-jps.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2.3/plugins/JavaEE/lib/javaee-jps.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2.3/plugins/IntelliLang/lib/java-langInjection-jps.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2.3/plugins/javaFX/lib/javaFX-jps.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2.3/plugins/javaFX/lib/javaFX-common.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2.3/plugins/Groovy/lib/groovy-jps.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2.3/plugins/Groovy/lib/groovy-constants-rt.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2.3/plugins/devkit/lib/devkit-jps.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2.3/plugins/JPA/lib/jps/javaee-jpa-jps.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2.3/plugins/ant/lib/ant-jps.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2.3/plugins/maven/lib/maven-jps.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2.3/plugins/gradle-java/lib/gradle-jps.jar" org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain 127.0.0.1 62881 2187d74b-6fdf-4d7c-bf66-07feee1c4808 C:/Users/dmatte/AppData/Local/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2022.2/compile-server
Build process started. Classpath: C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2.3/plugins/java/lib/jps-launcher.jar
2022-10-09 22:00:15,713 [    441]   WARN - #o.j.j.c.BuildMain - Cannot create event loop, attempt #0
java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to create a child event loop
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.java:88)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.java:60)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.java:49)
    at io.netty.channel.MultithreadEventLoopGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventLoopGroup.java:59)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.<init>(NioEventLoopGroup.java:87)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.<init>(NioEventLoopGroup.java:82)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.<init>(NioEventLoopGroup.java:69)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain.main(BuildMain.java:78)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:43)
Caused by: io.netty.channel.ChannelException: failed to open a new selector
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.openSelector(NioEventLoop.java:178)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.<init>(NioEventLoop.java:145)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.newChild(NioEventLoopGroup.java:183)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.newChild(NioEventLoopGroup.java:38)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.java:84)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to establish loopback connection
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer.run(PipeImpl.java:94)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer.run(PipeImpl.java:61)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl.<init>(PipeImpl.java:171)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SelectorProviderImpl.openPipe(SelectorProviderImpl.java:50)
    at java.base/java.nio.channels.Pipe.open(Pipe.java:155)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl.<init>(WindowsSelectorImpl.java:142)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorProvider.openSelector(WindowsSelectorProvider.java:44)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.openSelector(NioEventLoop.java:176)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Foi forçado o cancelamento de uma conexão existente pelo host remoto
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write0(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:51)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:113)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:79)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:50)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:463)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer$LoopbackConnector.run(PipeImpl.java:130)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer.run(PipeImpl.java:76)
    ... 24 more
2022-10-09 22:00:15,755 [    483]   WARN - #o.j.j.c.BuildMain - Cannot create event loop, attempt #1
java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to create a child event loop
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.java:88)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.java:60)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.java:49)
    at io.netty.channel.MultithreadEventLoopGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventLoopGroup.java:59)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.<init>(NioEventLoopGroup.java:87)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.<init>(NioEventLoopGroup.java:82)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.<init>(NioEventLoopGroup.java:69)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain.main(BuildMain.java:78)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:43)
Caused by: io.netty.channel.ChannelException: failed to open a new selector
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.openSelector(NioEventLoop.java:178)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.<init>(NioEventLoop.java:145)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.newChild(NioEventLoopGroup.java:183)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.newChild(NioEventLoopGroup.java:38)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.java:84)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to establish loopback connection
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer.run(PipeImpl.java:94)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer.run(PipeImpl.java:61)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl.<init>(PipeImpl.java:171)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SelectorProviderImpl.openPipe(SelectorProviderImpl.java:50)
    at java.base/java.nio.channels.Pipe.open(Pipe.java:155)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl.<init>(WindowsSelectorImpl.java:142)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorProvider.openSelector(WindowsSelectorProvider.java:44)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.openSelector(NioEventLoop.java:176)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Foi forçado o cancelamento de uma conexão existente pelo host remoto
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write0(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:51)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:113)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:79)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:50)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:463)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer$LoopbackConnector.run(PipeImpl.java:130)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer.run(PipeImpl.java:76)
    ... 24 more
Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:62881; reason: failed to create a child event loop
java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to create a child event loop
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.java:88)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.java:60)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.java:49)
    at io.netty.channel.MultithreadEventLoopGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventLoopGroup.java:59)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.<init>(NioEventLoopGroup.java:87)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.<init>(NioEventLoopGroup.java:82)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.<init>(NioEventLoopGroup.java:69)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain.main(BuildMain.java:78)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:43)
Caused by: io.netty.channel.ChannelException: failed to open a new selector
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.openSelector(NioEventLoop.java:178)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.<init>(NioEventLoop.java:145)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.newChild(NioEventLoopGroup.java:183)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.newChild(NioEventLoopGroup.java:38)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.java:84)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to establish loopback connection
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer.run(PipeImpl.java:94)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer.run(PipeImpl.java:61)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl.<init>(PipeImpl.java:171)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SelectorProviderImpl.openPipe(SelectorProviderImpl.java:50)
    at java.base/java.nio.channels.Pipe.open(Pipe.java:155)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl.<init>(WindowsSelectorImpl.java:142)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorProvider.openSelector(WindowsSelectorProvider.java:44)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.openSelector(NioEventLoop.java:176)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Foi forçado o cancelamento de uma conexão existente pelo host remoto
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write0(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:51)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:113)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:79)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:50)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:463)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer$LoopbackConnector.run(PipeImpl.java:130)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer.run(PipeImpl.java:76)
    ... 24 more
Exiting.
```

I'm using JDK 11.0.16 x64 with W10 SO and IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2.3 (Ultimate Edition) and, if needed, I can add more info.
Already tried to reinstall both IDEA and JDK.

Comment: the stack trace looks like a network issue, try disabling your firewall

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60907056/intellij-idea-error-abnormal-build-process-termination-failed-to-create-a-chi